# Getting python to work, Internal Server Error

Tags: python

I'm trying to get Python scripts, called from a web browser, to work. I keep getting the error:

```
500 Internal Server Error
```

When I check my error logs I see the message

```
Premature end of script headers
```

The only documentation of this error online says that it can be the result of having improper line return characters in your script, but I wrote my test script right from the shell with pico. Also, when I run the file from the command line it executes just fine. 
"
So far the only change I have made to apache is to add the .py to the "AddHandler cgi-script" line.

Thanks!

---

Thanks for the quick responses. Here is the latest version of the test code. I added a couple new lines before the output as suggested but still get the same error:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
print "Content-type: text/html\n"
print "\n\n"
print "<HTML>"
print "<HEAD>"
print "<TITLE>Test</TITLE>"
print "</HEAD>"
print "<BODY>"
print "<H2>Hi there.</h2>"
print "</BODY>"
print "</HTML>"
```

Some other details: I am running Apache 1.3 and don't have mod_python. I set apache to recognize .py as mentioned above. I am running the script from the main public_html folder.

---

An update. It doesn't seem to matter what I put in the shebang line. I tried all of the suggestions and even if I leave it blank the same error is showing up in the errors log and I'm getting a 500 error.

I'm running Apache/1.3.41 on linux (red hat 3.4) with WHM/Cpanel installed.

Answer (score 14):

This is the exact behavior you would get if your Python script does not have the executable permission set.

Try:

```
chmod a+x foo.py
```

(where foo.py is your script name).

See the [Apache tutorial](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/cgi.html#filepermissions) for more information.

Comment: heh, this is probably right.  Cant' believe I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 8):

do you have something like this at the top before you print anything else?

```
print "Content-type: text/html\n"
```

If you already have this, then post your code.

Comment: Two \n (HTTP requires an empty line after the headers)

Answer (score 6):

Two things spring immediately to mind.

1. Make sure you are outputting the `Content-Type: text/html` header
2. Make sure you are adding two newlines ("\n") after the headers before you output "Hello, world" or whatever.

Answer (score 5):

OK last guess:

Trying changing that shebang line to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/local/env python
```

It would also be helpful to know your platform / hosting provider.

Comment: Thanks!! @Triptych, it helped me. :)

Answer (score 3):

One common error is the wrong path. I my case it was usr/bin/python. The other common error is not transferring the file in ASCII mode. I am using WinSCP where you can set it easily: Go to Options->Preferences->Transfers->click Edit and change the mode to Text.

This code should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "<html><head>";
print "<title>CGI Test</title>";
print "</head><body>";
print "<p>Test page using Python</p>";
print "</body></html>";
```

Comment: God damn it man. I just spent all my morning trying to get this to work and it was a problem with the script itself.

Used your code and it worked.!! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you have configured Apaches httpd file correctly then you might be getting this error for following two reasons.Make sure these are correct.

1. Include '#!/usr/bin/python' or '#!C:/Python27/python' or accordingly in your script as first line.
2. Make sure there is space after print "Content-type: text/html" ie.
   print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
   Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can not believe that "1. Include '#!/usr/bin/python'.... " can be a reason.

Answer (score 2):

You may also get a better error message by adding this line at the top of your Python script:

`import cgitb; cgitb.enable()`

Also, the header should be capitalized `Content-Type`, not `Content-type`, although I doubt that that is breaking anything.

Comment: I added that line to the top of the script and capitalized "Type" but still am getting the same error and no additional information.

Comment: What does your shebang line look like?  
And what's your platform?

Comment: Indeed, capitalization does not matter for header names. The HTTP standard, RFC 2616, says in section 4.2 that HTTP headers have the same general syntax as the headers of RFC 822. And RFC 822, section  3.4.7, says that header names are case-insensitive.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, the problem is that you need to have two lines breaks after printing the content type. The following worked for me  :

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.6
print('Content-type: text/html\r\n')
print('\r\n')
print('Hello, World!')
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you're using a script written in Windows on a Unix machine, without first converting the line-endings from 0d0a to 0a.  It should be easy to convert it.  One way is with your ftp program;  transfer the file in ASCII mode.  The way I use with Metapad is to use File->FileFormat before saving.

Answer (score 1):

I tried many approaches to get Python working with Apache properly and finally settled with using **Apache + mod_WSGI + [web.py](http://webpy.org/cookbook/mod_wsgi-apache)** . It sounds like a lot, but it is much simpler than using the complicated frameworks like Django out there.

(You're right, don't bother with mod_python)

Note, I am using Apache2 , but mod_wsgi works on 1.3 as well, based on the [modwsgi page](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/).

If you are on Redhat, I believe you have yum, so make sure to get the apache wsgi module and other python packages:

```
$ yum update
$ yum install gcc gcc-c++ python-setuptools python-devel
$ yum install httpd mod_wsgi
```

And get web.py for your version of python. For example, using easy_install. I have v2.6.

```
$ easy_install-2.6 web.py
```

Create a directory for your python scripts : `/opt/local/apache2/wsgi-scripts/`

In your httpd.conf :

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so 

# note foo.py is the python file to get executed 
# and /opt/local/apache2/wsgi-scripts/ is the dedicated directory for wsgi scripts
WSGIScriptAlias /myapp /opt/local/apache2/wsgi-scripts/foo.py/

AddType text/html .py

<Directory /opt/local/apache2/wsgi-scripts/>

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Note that web.py uses a "templates directory". Put that into the wsgi directory , `/opt/local/apache2/wsgi-scripts/templates/`  .

Create a file `/opt/local/apache2/wsgi-scripts/templates/mytemplate.html` :

```
$def with (text)
<html>
<body>
Hello $text.
</body>
</html>
```

Add appropriate permissions.

```
$ chown -R root:httpd   /opt/local/apache2/wsgi-scripts/
$ chmod -R 770   /opt/local/apache2/wsgi-scripts/
```

In your python file, foo.py :

```
import web

urls = ( '/', 'broker',)
render = web.template.render('/opt/local/apache2/wsgi-scripts/templates/')

application = web.application(urls, globals()).wsgifunc()

class broker:
    def GET(self):
        return render.mytemplate("World")
```

The above will replace the special web.py $text variable in the mytemplate with the word "World" before returning the result .

http://ivory.idyll.org/articles/wsgi-intro/what-is-wsgi.html

Answer (score 1):

You can also get some of this same foolishness if you have DOS style end of lines on a linux web server.  (That just chewed up about two hours of my morning today.)  Off to update my vim.rc on this windows box that I need to use.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being a `dos2unix` issue for me. Ran `dos2unix test.py test.py` and it worked. The `\r\n` combinations were the problem. Had to `yum install dos2unix` to get it installed.